# Android decrease space or padding between icons in the action bar for actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, padding, menuitem

I want to remove space between menu items.as i shown in figure. i see a lots off answers of it and almost applied but it didn't work. i used actionbarsherlock. my styles are given below.

[image]

**Style**

```
 <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:height">@dimen/actionbar_height</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background__color</item>
 </style>
```

**V-11 Style**

```
 <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock" >
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_back_arrow</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back_arrow</item>

   <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/MYActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MYActionButtonStyle</item>    
   <!--  <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item> -->

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:height">@dimen/actionbar_height</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background__color</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>

    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>


</style>

 <style name="TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_textColor</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/actionbar_title_height</item>
</style>

<style name="MYActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton">
   <item name="android:maxWidth">10dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
</style>
```

**V-14 Style**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_back_arrow</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back_arrow</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:height">@dimen/actionbar_height</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background__color</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_textColor</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/actionbar_title_height</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved something like this by reducing the width of the icons used. This wasn't ideal because squared icons looked cramped together and it sort of goes against the android guidelined, but it worked.

Comment: how can i reduce the width of icons? by decrease the image size?

Comment: If you have an icon you use on the Action Bar that is squared (maybe 64x64), then reduce to something like 40x64 and you will a narrower button. As said, this may not be doable depending on the icons you have.

Answer (score 0):

Take custom layout and assign it to action bar.
Assign the layout to action bar in the activity.

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout);

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/actionbar_color" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/back_arrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_text"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/video"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/call" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/videocall" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/options_menu" />


</RelativeLayout>
```